# how to save flat file with dynamic column in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to take data from sql server database using for each loop and save into csv file and each time the number of columns are different so how can we achieve this in ssis.

i have tried in dataflow task but unable to find the solution.

Comment: You can use a C# script  task to take your dataset (saved to object variable) and send a name/path and it will generate a .csv automatically based off whatever data set you send it.  I am trying to find the code and will post in a few.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create a C# script task.  In there you will have 2 files (listed below):

Then you need to have 2
variables you pass to the script task:
This one is string type and contains the file name and path you want exported to like this C:\test.csv
User::FileExportNameAndPath

This one will be an OBJECT type and contains the data set from your SQL query.  You execute a SQL task and output results to OBJECT variable.
User::ObjDataToSaveToExportFile

If you use the same variable names above you will not have to edit the script code below at all.  You can even copy/paste the SSIS c# script task from one project to another and as long as you use the same variable names you wont have to edit anything

First one in Script Main:
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;    // this is to convert he object from SSIS to a data table
//using System.Text;

```
namespace ST_a8a7451a5662418eb87a1394e40bef29
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool IncludeHeaders = true;
            string FileNameAndPath = Dts.Variables["User::FileExportNameAndPath"].Value.ToString();
            
            

            // this gets the data object and sets ti to a data table
            OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::ObjDataToSaveToExportFile"].Value);

            // for test data
            //DataTable sourceTable = GetTestData();
            DataTable sourceTable = dt;

            //using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\dump.csv")) {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileNameAndPath))
            {
                // this calls the class in another file
                ConvertToCSV.WriteDataTable(sourceTable, writer, IncludeHeaders);
            }
    

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }// end main


        public DataTable GetTestData() 
        { 
            
            DataTable sourceTable = new DataTable();

            sourceTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Guid)),
                new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)),
                new DataColumn("StringValue", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("NumberValue", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("BooleanValue", typeof(bool))
            });

            sourceTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String1", 100, true);
            sourceTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String2", 200, false);
            sourceTable.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String3", 300, true);



            return sourceTable;
        }// end get teest data


        public static class Extensions
        {
            public static string ToCSV(DataTable table)
            {
                var result = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Append(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                    result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                        result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
                    }
                }

                return result.ToString();
            }
        }



        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }// end class
}// end namespace
```

Send File named: ConvertToCSV.cs  (though you can probably combine them into the main file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace ST_a8a7451a5662418eb87a1394e40bef29
{
    class ConvertToCSV
    {

        public static void WriteDataTable(DataTable sourceTable, TextWriter writer, bool includeHeaders) 
        {
            if (includeHeaders) {
                IEnumerable<String> headerValues = sourceTable.Columns
                    .OfType<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(column => QuoteValue(column.ColumnName));
                
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headerValues));
            }

            IEnumerable<String> items = null;

            foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows) {
                items = row.ItemArray.Select(o => QuoteValue(o.ToString()));                
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", items));
            }

            writer.Flush();
        }// end Write Data Table


        // this function adds quotes around the strings for text qualified values
        private static string QuoteValue(string value)
        {
            return String.Concat("\"",
            value.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"");
        }



    }
}
```